# mocking ExecutorService invokeAll method in java

Tags: java, mockito, executorservice, invokeall

I am trying to mock the ExecutorService but it is constantly giving compile error. The code that I am trying is the following:

```
ExecutorService executorService = mock(ExecutorService.class);
Future<A> mockedFuture = mock(Future.class);
List<Future<A>> list = Lists.newArrayList(mockedFuture);

when(executorService.invokeAll(any())).thenReturn(list);
```

When I compile this, it returns the following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(List<Future<A>>)
[javac]         when(executorService.invokeAll(any())).thenReturn(futureList);
[javac]                                               ^
[javac]     method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(List<Future<Object>>) is not applicable
[javac]       (argument mismatch; List<Future<A>> cannot be converted to List<Future<Object>>)
[javac]     method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(List<Future<Object>>,List<Future<Object>>...) is not applicable
[javac]       (argument mismatch; List<Future<A>> cannot be converted to List<Future<Object>>)
```

any idea?

Comment: Try `executorService.<A>invokeAll(any())`.

Answer (score 2):

Here `Mockito.any()` returns a type inferred by the target of the invocation, that is `executorService.invokeAll()`.   But `executorService.invokeAll()` doesn't declare a more specific type either as it also relies on the target inference : `Mockito.when(...)`.

The type returned by `any()` depends on the type returned by `invokeAll()` that depends on the type returned by `when()`.

But neither `invokeAll()` nor `when()` specifies the `A` type in the generic collection.

So the generic `T` type of the `invokeAll()` method defined as :

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

will be seen by the compiler as `Object` such as :

```
<Object> List<Future<Object>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<Object>> tasks)
```

And so `any()` will return a `Collection<? extends Callable<Object>>` type.

In these conditions, `thenReturn()` that doesn't return a `List<Future<Object>>` but a `List<Future<A>>` declared type cannot compile :

> ```
> argument mismatch; List<Future<A>> cannot be converted to List<Future<Object>>)
> ```

To solve your issue, you need to do an unchecked cast on `Mockito.any()` (but you know that it will work):

```
Mockito.when(executorService.invokeAll((Collection<Callable<A>>)Mockito.any())).thenReturn(list);
```

Or as alternative, solve the target inference by setting explicitly the return of `Mockito.any()` in a variable  :

```
Collection<Callable<A>> any = Mockito.any();
Mockito.when(executorService.invokeAll(any)).thenReturn(list);
```

Comment: Casing works for solving the compile error. But when I run the test, it gives the following runtime error:

[junit] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

Especially on this line:

Comment: Pointing this line:    --->     List<Callable<Void>> anyList = any();

Answer (score 1):

You should have more success with:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = mock(ExecutorService.class);
    Future<Object> mockedFuture = mock(Future.class);
    List<Future<Object>> list = Lists.newArrayList(mockedFuture);

    when(executorService.invokeAll(any())).thenReturn(list);
```

There's a clue for this the error message:

```
argument mismatch; List<Future<A>> cannot be converted to List<Future<Object>>
```

That's because with Java generics, `List<Future<A>` is not a `List<Future<Object>>` (nor is `Future<A>` a `Future<Object>`).

There are many good explanations for why this is the case, have a look on SO for Java contravariance.